# Load partial view on same page on click

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My Edit Customer page have a partial view that shows all his/hers invoices:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("_ShowInvoices", "Adresser", new { id = Model.Adressid });}
```

That partial view have this link to open the Invoice Edit page in a new page:

```
Html.ActionLink(item.InvoiceNr, "Edit", "Invoice", new { id = item.InvoiceNr }, null)
```

But now I want to open the Invoice Edit page in another partial view on my Edit Custormer page. So I changed the link on the Invoice Edit page to

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(item.InvoiceNr.ToString(), "EditInvoice", "Invoice", new { id = item.InvoiceNr }, new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "edit_invoices" })
```

Invoice Controller:

```
    public PartialViewResult EditInvoce(int id)
    {
        Invoices invoice = db.Prens.Find(id);
        return PartialView("_InvoiceEdit", invoice);
    }
```

And added this to my Edit Customer page

```
        <div id="edit_invoices">
            @Html.Partial("_InvoiceEdit")
        </div>
```

Which for now contains this so I can see if its workning..

```
@model Pren.Models.Invoices
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.InvoiceNr)
```

I've also added this to my Customer Edit page

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The error I get is (Pren.Models.Adress is the customer model)

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Pren.Models.Adress', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Pren.Models.Invoices'.
>
> Line 138:                @Html.Partial("_InvoiceEdit")

So where am I wrong? Is @Html.Partial() the wrong one to use? Should I do this another way? Give me your input please!

Comment: What happens when you remove the `@Html.Partial("_InvoiceEdit")` from div `edit_invoices`?

Comment: That, including some typos fixed my problem, hah!

Comment: I included that as an answer. I'm going to edit your question to remove the answer from it, as that is confusing.

Comment: Unless you really want to render something on page load, then your ViewModel for your view will need a property containing the ViewModel for your partial view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leave the `@Html.Partial("_InvoiceEdit")` out of:

```
<div id="edit_invoices">
    @Html.Partial("_InvoiceEdit")
</div>
```

Mainly because you should pass a model to it like `@Html.Partial("_InvoiceEdit", model)`, and since the model for that page isn't the correct type, it wouldn't work anyway (hence, your error).

The `@Ajax.ActionLink` will handle loading the partial into `<div id="edit_invoices">`.

Answer (score 0):

You are required to pass the model for `_InvoiceEdit` like below

```
   @Html.Partial("_InvoiceEdit", invoices)
```

This will render the partial view with the same request that returns Address model, however your _InvoiceEdit requires type of invoice. In this case, we need to populate the invoices and send it to the view to use it for rendering.

***Option 2:***

If you are not populating the invoices as part of current action, you can initiate a new request to get the invoices based on the id.

```
  @{Html.RenderAction("EditInvoice", "Invoices", new { id = Model.id});}
```